# Docker container is always persistent?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I was trying to start a Tomcat container, then made a text file into its /root directory. After I restarted the container, I found that the text file remains as if the directory is using a docker volume.

When I looked into [the Dockerfile which constructed the image](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/27c69186d320837884e9ed56db504b92e454f6d5/7/jre7/Dockerfile), I found that no volume definition is defined. Why is this possible? I was expecting to see the text file gone.

This is how I started the container `docker run -p 8801:8080 --name tom tomcat`

Comment: Seems you just stop the container but not remove it. A stopped container remains existing.

Comment: Then, what's the point of having volume with naming option? A volume which is named, will remains if the container is removed. If not named, it will be deleted as well.

Comment: The point is performance.

Comment: Sorry. I don't get it. Now, take a look at https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/ad625c64a06e16683e997e5a0147508d115f4989/8.0/Dockerfile. So, it's useless to define VOLUME there?

Comment: Sure you can ignore the `VOLUME` instruction there and you will get a working image as well. `VOLUME` is more or less similar to the `EXPOSE` instruction. It is used to expose a mounting point. In this database scenario, you are strongly encouraged to use `VOLUME` in the Dockerfile.

Comment: I just noticed that `EXPOSE` means nothing than a documentation (according to its official documebtation). But I couldn't find similar for `VOLUME`. I need a good reference if u don't mind.

Comment: @BMitch gives a great explanation about `VOLUME` in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620300/what-is-the-purpose-of-dockerfile-command-volume. Check it out.

Comment: I think I know the purpose of VOLUME. It's to define a mountable disk within the docker itself. I guess @Yuankun, you're right about persistency. Container is always persistent.